# Sort files by date but folders by name

Tags: c#, sorting, icomparer

In attempt to show folders sorted by name at the top and then files underneeth sorted by date I have made this PropertyGroupDescription and IComparer

```
using (ItemCollectionView.DeferRefresh())
{

    var dataView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_fileCollection);
    PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("ObjectType");
    dataView.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
    dataView.CustomSort = new StringComparerFiles(false);  
}


public class StringComparerFiles : IComparer 
{

    public StringComparerFiles() : this(false) { }
    public StringComparerFiles(bool descending) { }
    //descending not implemented yet
    public int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        bool xFolder = false;
        bool yFolder = false;
        string xName = string.Empty;
        string yName = string.Empty;
        DateTime xDate = new DateTime();
        DateTime yDate = new DateTime();


        if (a is FileData)
        {
            xDate = (a as FileData).FileDate; 
        }
        else
        {
            xFolder = true;
            xName = (a as FolderData).FolderName;
        }

        if (b is FileData)
        {
            yDate = (b as FileData).FileDate; 
        }
        else
        {
            yFolder = true;
            yName = (b as FolderData).FolderName;
        }


        if (xFolder && yFolder)
        {
            int n = SafeNativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(xName, yName);
            return n;
        }
        else if (xFolder || yFolder) 
            return 0;  //don't compare file and folder
        else
        {
            return DateTime.Compare(xDate, yDate);
        }              
    }
}
```

Result is that I get folders listed first but only some sorted by date. Is my logic for IComparer correct?

Comment: Split, sort each subset separately and concat back would be so much easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compare a file against a folder, they shouldn't be considered equivalent, but the folder should come first.

Comment: This good answer may be coded has follow: _else if (xFolder || yFolder) return xfolder ? -1 : +1_

Comment: @Graffito This is correct solution that does not even need GroupDescriptions. Can you make this sentence into official answer so I can accept it. Thanks